# Defaulting camera sharing permissions in Firefox for Android

Tags: android, browser, barcode-scanner, quaggajs, firefox-android

I'm developing a barcode scanning page for our warehouse, to enable the guys to scan in barcodes of goods coming in and out, and manage properties like dimensions and weights where they can. Since this ties in directly to our in-house CRM, we've decided to build it as a part of the CRM itself.

I've been using QuaggaJS to handle the barcode scanning, and we're only using Firefox for Android to run the scanner since Chrome has various issues with getting the back-facing camera instead of the front.

**Can anyone suggest a way to stop the "Would you like to share your camera with..." on certain pages/domains?** Since the page will be used quite frequently and quickly, having this pop up every single time is becoming cumbersome and I can't find any information on how to disable it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it under in the `about:config`.  Search for `media.navigator` and find an option:

`media.navigator.permission.disabled` change the value from `false` to `true`

**Note:** Use it wisely as it introduces a security hole.  This option was meant for developers.

Comment: Beat me by 8 seconds >_>

Comment: @newplayer65 Ah, sorry about that.  Next time you win :).

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting discussion on the exact topic [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1005233). Apparently there's a Firefox developer setting called `media.navigator.permission` that you can set to `disabled`.

> There is a pref (media.navigator.permission.disabled) to disable the permission check, but that pref is meant for developers and is not recommended for normal usage, so be cautious with using it because this introduces security risks.

Comment: This seems like it'd be the best option. The phones will only be hooked into a local, sandboxed network connection. No 4G, no open WiFi, and they'll never leave work premises. I'll give it a shot and see if it works